# Let $A$ be a $3$X$3$ matrix whose eigenvalues are $1$, $2$, $3$. Find $\det(B)$ where $B = A^2 + A^T$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a $3$X$3$ matrix whose eigenvalues are $1$, $2$, $3$. Find $\det(B)$ where $B = A^2 + A^T$.

I know that $\det(A) = 6$, but I cannot proceed after $|A^2 + A^T|$. Any hints as to how to approach the problem?

Comment: Is $A$ assumed to be symmetric or something?

Comment: Double post. cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147566/find-deta2at-when-eigenvalues-are-1-2-3?rq=1

Comment: @loupblanc thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, it seems, is that it depends.  If we have $$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 
\end{array}
\right]$$
Then we have $\det(A^2 + A^T) = 120$.

On the other hand, if we have $$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3 
\end{array}
\right]$$

Then we have $\det(A^2 + A^T) = 144$.